# Seeding tags for Suggestion List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using Rails(v3) gem `acts-as-taggable-on` for tagging some user data - interests & locations.

I would like to seed the "locations" tag and present a suggestion list to user for selecting the location. Basically the user can only select from the seeded locations and not create any new location.

So this is 2 part question -

1. Is it possible to seed (or Ok) to seed the `tags` and `taggings` table with locations data?
2. Does the gem have built in methods for a list of tags for a particular context (locations in this case)?

Also I am guessing if seeding tag data is ok, then I would need to do this -

```
tag = Tag.create(:name => 'New York')
Tagging.create(:tag_id => tag.id, :context => 'locations')
```

Here's the definition of tagging tables -

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/generators/acts_as_taggable_on_migration/templates/migration.rb